# What could be causing this code to NOT allow re-entry into springboard?

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I have an app which uploads images to a bunch of places at once, kinda like Instagram style.

It is setup with an `NSOperationQueue` that runs a bunch of `NSOperation` wrappers around an an asynchronous `NSURLConnection`.

Most questions that begin like this end in "the callbacks don't get called because the calling thread is joined before they return. This is **not** that kind of question. I *am* getting my callbacks as expected, but I am also somehow preventing the app from backgrounding when the home button is pressed. I always thought this was not able to be blocked at all due to sandboxing, but somehow I have done it. Pressing the home button while the operations are running will do nothing until they are complete, at which point (20-30sec later) the app properly backgrounds.

**NB This seems to only happen on single core processor devices. I can reproduce only on my iPhone 4, but not my 4S or iPad 3.*

Still interested? Here is my setup:

```
self.uploadQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[self.uploadQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
[self.uploadQueue setSuspended:YES];
```

Later on, I add operations to the queue and then unsuspend it to start. Here is some code from those `NSOperation` subclasses:

```
- (BOOL)isConcurrent { return YES; }
- (BOOL)isExecuting { return self.executing; }
- (BOOL)isFinished { return self.finished; }

- (void)start {
    // Omitted: check for cancel...
    // Omitted: check if setup to run

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    self.executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    [self.sharer share];    
    CFRunLoopRun();
}


- (void)completeOperation {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

The `share` method sets up an asynchronous `NSURLConnection` and fires it off like so:

```
- (void)share {
    // Omitted: connection setup
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:postRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){
        // handle error or success, then call
        [self.currentOperation completeOperation];
    }];
```

Aside from the side-effect I am trying to solve for, the code *works* in that it does what it is supposed to, the callbacks get called, the threads stay alive as long as they need to, and the operation queue only runs the specified number of operations at a time.

What have I tried? I tried:

1. Calling the NSURLConnection on the `[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]`. This caused the async connection to not callback the block.
2. Forcing each NSOperation onto the main thread in the `start` method. This did not solve the problem, also caused code to sometime not work and the UI to sometimes freeze.
3. Implementing my own queue with a mutable array and GCD to get on the right dispatch thread. Couldn't get it to work.
4. Synchronous NSURLConnections in the operations. I didn't really try this because it is not an option for me. Some of the network frameworks such as the Facebook iOS SDK do not have a synchronous option.

Pausing execution during the time after the home-button press, but before the operations are done yields nothing interesting. There doesn't seem to be anything on the main thread waiting for a lock or execution to finish.

[image: Threads 1][image: Threads 2]

Am I setting this up like a complete bozo? What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just wondering - have you tried running it on a device with a release build, unattached to the debugger? I wonder if maybe you're able to keep yourself running because the watchdog process isn't as strict when you're running a debug build. If that's not the case, maybe file a bug report with apple.

Comment: Ya, I have tried with an Ad-Hoc build with same results. It was a beta tester who brought this to my attention.

Comment: I have always found that getting "concurrent" NSOperation subclasses to perform correct to be very error prone. Apple's own [QA1712](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1712/_index.html) describes this as "quite tricky."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Turns out all this networking stuff was a red herring. It was some looping CAAnimations which were preventing return to springboard somehow.

Original Guesses:

My guess: you shouldn't be calling `CFRunLoopRun` in your start method; the start method of a concurrent operation is expected to return before the operation is complete and finish later. You're probably holding on to some GCD lock (thread?) that the system needs to dispatch other tasks.

If you need to monopolize a thread via `CFRunLoopRun`, you should kick off your own thread in `start` and then return. I think it would be easier, though, just to not use NSOperation and kick off your (already async) url connections from the main thread, keeping an array of things to share when each one is finished.

Actually, I think the problem is `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())`: you're running this on the *main thread*, so you're stopping the main run loop!

Comment: Hmm, Just tried it this way... still prevents the app from exiting. I completely removed the nsoperations and am calling from the main thread.

Comment: Are you still can `CFRunLoopRun`? I'm also going to add another idea.

Comment: No, the runloop stuff was in the operation, which now i am not using. I added a toggle in my app to switch it off while i am debugging. Now it is just an array that runs the async connections 1 at a time, firing the next one off on the previous ones completion block.

Comment: I was going to suggest just using a concurrent operation, removing all the isExecuting/etc stuff and then you should be able to do your current CFRunLoopRun logic in your main method after starting the sharing; I've added another thought to the answer. My only other thought at the moment is that there might be something else to blame?

Comment: The CFRunLoopStop is actually running on the same thread that it was started on so thats not the issue here.

Comment: re: Concurrency. It was my understanding that nice the NSOperationQueue switch to GCD, the thread is called on a separate thread no matter what (see the QA article posted in the comments above). I will give it a go though and see if there is any change in the behavior

Comment: The code posted above looks like the `CFRunLoopStop` is running on the main queue; is there some other code that moves it to the background thread somehow? As for the switch to GCD: the QA article I posted says the "start method must be prepared to run on any thread"; you might not be able to assume that you can monopolize that thread as you are doing here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13220/discussion-between-coneybeare-and-jesse-rusak)